# Move previous next buttons in R's slickR carousel

Tags: css, r, shiny, slickr

I can successfully move the "next" button for slickR's carousel. However, when I use the similar method to move the "previous" button it does not work. The action and the mouseover no longer work. Why is this? How can I move the "prev" button and maintain full functionality?

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slickR/slickR.pdf) refers to an element in settings called, `appendArrows`. But it is not clear to me how to use this.

```
appendArrows character, Change where the navigation arrows are attached (Selector, htmlString, Array, Element, jQuery object), Default: $(element)
```

Here is where the fully functional moved buttons should appear:
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

# Test #########################################################################
chart_names_list <- c( "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+1", 
                                                "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+2",
                                                "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+3")
num_slides <- 2


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
    .slick-next {
      right: 163px;
      top: 20px;
    }
    .slick-prev {
      left: 670px;
      top: 20px;
    }
    .slick-slide {
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
      
    ")
    )
  ),
  
  slickROutput("slick_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$slick_output <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(obj = chart_names_list, height = 300, width = "100%") +
      settings(dots = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendArrows` parameter is used to tell in which `div` class the arrows should be displayed.

This shows the principle, but still needs some extra `css` to get exactly the result you expect :

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

# Test #########################################################################
chart_names_list <- c( "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+1", 
                       "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+2",
                       "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+3")
num_slides <- 2


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .arrows {
      height: 30px;}"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6,),
    column(2,
  tags$div(class="arrows"
      )),column(4)),
  slickROutput("slick_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$slick_output <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(obj = chart_names_list, height = 300, width = "100%") +
      settings(dots = TRUE, appendArrows = '.arrows')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Can you show how this would work in an Rmarkdown, no Shiny approach?

Comment: This seems a bit trickier in RMarkdown, and didn't succeed with a [css chunck](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html#html-css) followed by `<div class = "arrows"></div>` : it has an effect, but I didn't manage to place the buttons properly.

Comment: OK. Last question. It works well on a desktop but viewed on an iphone the image is cutoff. ie it is not responsive. See: https://iframe.whatbank.ca/tmp/ which uses: height = 300, width = "100%" Do I need to add responsive behaviour manually? The original JS page talks about it, https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ but I'm not sure how to translate that to R.

Comment: Looks really cool! I won't be able to help for responsiveness : outside my swim lane ;-). One question on my side : could you share the css to make the buttons near each other?

Comment: Also on a desktop PC this solution only works for certain window sizes.

Comment: @ismirsehregal, thanks, I didn't know the `calc` function in css : upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

As this is the original question regarding the positioning of the arrow buttons, I guess it's worth mentioning, that @ixodid realized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841891/make-slickr-carousel-responsive/67868091#67868091), that @Waldi's [column-approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815894/9841389) is no longer working when the browser window is resized.

The following is a workaround regarding this:

```
library("shiny")
library("slickR")

chart_names_list <- c( "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+1", 
                       "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+2",
                       "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+3")
num_slides <- 3

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
    .arrows {
      height: 20px;
    }
    .slick-prev {
      left: calc(100% - 60px);
    }
    .slick-next {
      left: calc(100% - 35px);
    }
    .slick-slide img {
    width: 100% !important;
    }
    "))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, tags$div(class="arrows"))
  ),
  slickROutput("slick_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$slick_output <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(obj = chart_names_list, height = 300) +
      settings(dots = TRUE, appendArrows = '.arrows')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Added image to question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Waldi's valuable suggestions and adding some css leads to a complete answer below.

```
library("shiny")
library("slickR")

# Test #########################################################################
chart_names_list <- c( "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+1", 
                       "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+2",
                       "http://placehold.it/900x500/39CCCC/ffffff&text=Slide+3")
num_slides <- 3


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
    .arrows {
      height: 30px;
    }
    .slick-prev {
      left: 230px;  # moves right
    }
    .slick-next {
      left: 250px;  # moves right
    }
    "))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6,),
    column(2,
           tags$div(class="arrows"
           )),
    column(4)),
  
  slickROutput("slick_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$slick_output <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(obj = chart_names_list, height = 300, width = "100%") +
      settings(dots = TRUE, appendArrows = '.arrows')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the `css`!